# How to sync data between realm and webserver?

Tags: realm

I want to develop a feature which will work offline and when connected to network will sync the data with web server? Any ideas are appreciated . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Realm Mobile Platform](https://realm.io/products/realm-mobile-platform/) if you don't want to implement your own custom solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing seems to fit with features that we currently offer as part of the Enterprise Edition of the platform. We provide a server-side client that allows to build integration with third party services, such as long-term storage databases and other data at rest.

As far as I know, it's not possible to do this with the Developer Edition.